# Apps script export data to another spreadsheet, build it in xlsx and attach it to email

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the problem with one project. The task is:

1. Export data from one spreadsheet to second spreadsheet - function expData
2. Rebuild second spreadsheet to xlsx-format - function getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel
3. Send email with xlsx-attachment some receivers - function getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel

```js
var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
var url1 = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16W0E_FCW-C_1ZVV_BOQgSAdT_MhRZs-KOQhYsRcZi6o/edit?usp=sharing";
let sprShIn = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url1);

function expData() {
  
  let url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
  let sprShOut = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  let shOut = sprShOut.getSheetByName("Сводная таблица 1");
  let lRowOut =  shOut.getRange("A6:A").getValues().filter(String).length;
  let data = shOut.getRange('A6:E' + (lRowOut + 5)).getValues(); //assign the range you want to copy
    
  let shIn = sprShIn.getSheetByName('fXLSX');

  let lRowIn =  shIn.getRange("A1:A").getValues().filter(String).length;
  shIn.deleteRows(2, lRowIn);
  lRowIn =  shIn.getRange("A1:A").getValues().filter(String).length;
  shIn.getRange(lRowIn + 1, 1, lRowOut,shIn.getLastColumn()).setValues(data); 

}

function getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel(){

  try {

    let sprShOut = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    //let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url1);
    let url2 = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + sprShIn.getId() + "&exportFormat=xlsx";
    let params = {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };

    let blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, params).getBlob();
    let datetimeMsg = new Date().toLocaleString();

    blob.setName(datetimeMsg + "_JSON.xlsx");

  let shOut = sprShOut.getSheetByName("адреса для рассылки");
  let rowsAmount = shOut.getRange("A1:A").getValues().filter(String).length;
  let dataRange = shOut.getRange(1, 1, rowsAmount, 1);
  let data = dataRange.getValues();
  let emailAddress = "";

    for (i in data) {
      var row = data[i];
      // Из первого столбца берем адрес
      if (emailAddress == "") {emailAddress = row[0];}
      else {emailAddress = emailAddress + ", " + row[0];}
    }

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "Google Sheet to Excel", "The XLSX file is attached", {attachments: [blob]});

  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
}

function doJOB(){
  expData();
  Utilities.sleep(5000); //trying make timeout
  getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel();
}
```

If I start both functions one after another separately, everything works good, data goes to another spreadsheet, another spreadsheet builds to xlsx-format, mail sends with xlsx-attachment.

But if I start function doJOB, data does not have time to be exported as the letter is already sent with an empty  xlsx-file. I was trying to enter timeout with different milliseconds but it did not help. What's wrong? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that in this case, in order to reflect the change of the sheet of "fXLSX" in `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url1)`, I would like to propose the following modification in the function of `doJOB()`.

#### From:

```
Utilities.sleep(5000);
```

#### To:

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

#### Reference:

- [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is helpful!))) Everything works correctly!

Comment: @Dmitriy Rudakov Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.